# Find which point is nearest to a multipolygon postgis

Tags: sql, postgresql, location, geospatial, postgis

I am given a few geometry point which is made of

ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(b.longitude,b.latitude),4326).

I have a example table called 'state' which contains multipolygon data as below :

```
gid,|pa_code  |pa_name   |     code,         |  geom 
"1" | "0800"  | 0800"   |"3.12306415134995" |"0106000060E61000000100000"
"2" | "0801"  | 0801"   |"3.12455415134995" |"0106000060E61000000800000"
```

The geom column is loaded from .shp file with column type : GEOMETRY(MultiPolygonM,4326) )

Question :

How can i know if a point is inside a multipolygon?

I tried using code as below but it takes forever to load and uses up my storage:

```
Select a.name,a.suburb
from point a, state b
where st_contains(b.geom,a.geom) AND a.id NOTNULL AND a.datetime::DATE = '2017-01-01'
```

Also , i noticed i generated the .shp file and the column type is GEOMETRY(MultiPolygonM,4326).

What is the difference between GEOMETRY(MultiPolygon,4326) and GEOMETRY(MultiPolygonM,4326)?

Comment: st_intersects(b.geom,a.geom) is faster than st_contains(b.geom,a.geom)

Comment: what if the multipolygons are overlapping? how does the point know which multipolygons to choose?